# Perl - want to extract the lines between a pattern

Tags: perl, file

I have a text file like this

```
< MSSQLSTART >

select metric,value,Date 
from temp1

< MSSQLEND >

< MYSQL-START >

select metric,value,Date 
from temp1

< MYSQL-END >
```

now I want to extract the lines between the specific tags. technically want to extract those two sql queries from the file and execute the those queries and save the results to separate files and compare both the results.

it will be very helpful if somebody can help me to code this in perl

I have tried extracting lines with the below code but it prints the entire file if the strings are matching but not between the lines...

```
use strict;
use warnings;

undef $/;        
open (FILE, '<', 'input.txt') or die "Could not open file: $!";

while (<FILE>) {
  print $_ if /<MSSQLSTART>/../<MSSQLEND>/;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why did you `undef $/`? It loads the whole file at once. Don't touch the variable if you want to process the file line by line.

If you want to extract the lines without the tags, you can check the value returned from the flip-flop operator: it returns a line count starting from 1, the last line's number has `E0` appended:

```
while (<FILE>) {
    my $i = /< MYSQL-START >/ .. /< MYSQL-END >/;                                             # SO syntax highlighting bug /
    if ($i && $i != 1 && $i !~ /E0$/) {
        print;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does setting `$i` do in this context? Can you not just do it with a range operator?

Comment: @Sobrique: I couldn't think of a way to check that the range operator is different to 1 and doesn't end in `E0` in one step.

Comment: @Sobrique: `print if (/< MYSQL-START >/ .. /< MYSQL-END >/) !~ /(?:^1?|E0)$/;` works, but isn't really readable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fh, "<", "abc.txt" or die "Could not open file: $!";

while (<$fh>) {
    if (/< .*START >/../< .*END >/)
    {
        print $_ unless /< .*START >/ or /< .*END >/;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
select metric,value,Date 
from temp1


select metric,value,Date 
from temp1
```